# Null pointer Exception Android json parsing using Volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using Json parsing using Volley concept,I got null pointer Exception  this line "AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);" please give a solution. thank you

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,Allbooksurl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject object) {
        try {
            String result = object.getString("status");
                            Log.d(result, "result");
                            String message = object.getString("info");
                            Log.d(message, "message");
                            JSONArray responserecentbooks= object.getJSONArray("recentbooks");
                            for (int i = 0; i < responserecentbooks.length(); i++)
                            {
                                JSONObject person = (JSONObject) responserecentbooks.get(i);
                                String id = person.getString("id");
                                String name = person.getString("name");
                                    db.insertValue(id, name);

 }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        //VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

try {
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the log cat.  And also to the guy posted above. Can you please tell me how is it a possible duplicate.

Comment: Check your `AppController` instance. It may be null

Comment: i posted updated code @PiyushGupta

Comment: Check my answer and also show getInstance() method

Comment: Add 2 things to your question. 1) code for app controller class and 2) your crash report I.e logcat

Comment: i implement all in correct way ,i did minar mistake in manifeast ,thanks for your support guys

Comment: you should post all logcat here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 I forget to declare this in manifeast
    <application
    android:name="com.example.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"></application>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error clearly says that `Null pointer Exception` at

```
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

So your instance of `AppController` class may be null in `getInstance()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your `AppController` can be null. Check your code, should be like:

```
    private static AppController INSTANCE;
    public static AppController getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE = this;
    }
```